# What is the purpose of ACCESS_FAST in OpenCV 3.0?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

To get cv::UMat from a cv::Mat in OpenCV 3.0, you use this function :

```
UMat cv::Mat::getUMat(int accessFlags, UMatUsageFlags usageFlags=USAGE_DEFAULT )
```

the variable `accessFlags` is an enumeration type that takes one of the values below:

```
enum { ACCESS_READ=1<<24, ACCESS_WRITE=1<<25,
    ACCESS_RW=3<<24, ACCESS_MASK=ACCESS_RW, ACCESS_FAST=1<<26 };
```

What is the purpose of using the value `ACCESS_FAST`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ACCESS_FAST` is only used in the [`allocate`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/afdbd855ee980064bcad8a95bcf44c53b7d5f7d7/modules/core/src/ocl.cpp#L4381) function to [use `memcpy`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/afdbd855ee980064bcad8a95bcf44c53b7d5f7d7/modules/core/src/ocl.cpp#L4413) or [create a temporary mat](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/afdbd855ee980064bcad8a95bcf44c53b7d5f7d7/modules/core/src/ocl.cpp#L4460) if `ACCESS_FAST` is *not* specified. It was [added to OpenCV](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/0a07d780e0024b2a9b927d16bf3ff8513082a3ba) as part of its OpenCL Shared Virtual Memory support.

`cv::Mat::getUMat()` will `allocate` a new `UMat` and return it, forwarding `accessFlags` when allocating the new matrix. If you aren't building OpenCV with OpenCL support, then `ACCESS_FAST` seems mostly useless.

I'm afraid that's the limit of my knowledge. Someone more experienced with OpenCV will have to provide more a detailed answer/documentation on exactly what `ACCESS_FAST` is intended for.